# OpenCV findContours not working

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, webcam, contour

I've been stuck with this issue for a few days now and you are my last hope, stackoverflow!

Windows 7, Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, OpenCV 2.4.8.

**Source:**

```
int main(){

    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
    if(!capture.isOpened()){
        printf("Capture failure\n");
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat frame;
    capture >> frame;
    if(frame.empty()) return -1;

    cv::namedWindow("Video");
    cv::namedWindow("Contour");

    while(true){
        capture >> frame;
        if(frame.empty()) break;

        cv::Mat cont = frame;

        cv::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
        cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

        cv::threshold(cont, cont, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
        cv::inRange(cont, cv::Scalar(128, 128, 128), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), cont);

        cv::findContours(cont, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        for(size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); i++){
            cv::drawContours(frame, contours, i, cv::Scalar(0,255,255), 10);
        }

        cv::imshow("Contour", cont);
        cv::imshow("Video", frame);

        if(cv::waitKey(10)==27 ) break;
    }

    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

Fairly simple code, right? If it's not obvious, what I want to do is get all the contours from my webcam with `cv::inRange` applied. That's it.

This code gives me `cv::Exception at memory location 0x0045F7CC`.

**Edit**: Also gives me `OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats ([Start]FindContours supported only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images) in cvStartFindContours, file ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp` from the command line.

I've seen examples using `cv::findContours()` and all of them shows that you need a binary `cv::Mat` which I get from `cv::threshold()` or `cv::inRange()` but it still doesen't work for me. Help!

Comment: oh, wait, - threshold produces a binary, 1channel image. you can't apply inRange on that. so either: - convert to grayscale and threshold, - *or* inRange

Comment: Yeah, comment the `inRange()` line out and you'll still get the same error.

Comment: the error comes from which function ?

Comment: also, please : cv::Mat cont = frame.clone(); // else they're the same after the assignment

Comment: @berak I don't know which function who is the cause of the error. I still get the same error using `frame.clone()`. Thanks.

Comment: [`threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?#threshold) and [`findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#findcontours) expect single channel image as input. You are passing 3 channel image to both. You should convert `frame` to grayscale before thresholding.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it! Here's the code:

```
while(true){
    capture >> frame;
    if(frame.empty()) break;

    cv::Mat cont, threshold;
    cont = frame.clone();
    cv::cvtColor(cont, cont, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

    cv::threshold(cont, cont, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    threshold = cont.clone();

    cv::findContours(cont, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for(size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); i++){
        cv::drawContours(frame, contours, i, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
    }

    cv::imshow("Contour", threshold);
    cv::imshow("Video", frame);

    if(cv::waitKey(10)==27 ) break;      
}
```

Comment: please explain your solution

Comment: @NicolasGervais, I wrote this 7 years ago. I'm pretty certain I didn't understand the code completely then, and I can assure you I'm still not understanding OpenCV enough today to explain what fixed the issue. Though sgarizvi's comment to the original question seems to have pointed me in the right direction. Good luck! And feel free to attempt to edit my answer if you do find the reason as to why it works.